# Terraform: Can not parse "ip_configuration.0.subnet_id" as a resource id - invalid URI for request: Nested

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Also for public ip id getting:  "

> Error: Can not parse "ip_configuration.0.public_ip_address_id" as a
> resource id: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse
> module.resource.azurerm_public_ip.primary.id: invalid URI for request
> "

As the network is a nested module for the resource module, will you please suggest, where I'm missing?

main.tf file:

```
#Select provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  version = "~> 2.2"
  features {}
}

module "resource" {
  source = "./modules/resource"
  resource_group_name = "DevOpsPoc-primary"
  location = "southeastasia"
}

module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  virtual_network = "primaryvnet"
  subnet = "primarysubnet"
  address_space = "192.168.0.0/16"
  address_prefix = "192.168.1.0/24"
  public_ip = "backendvmpip"
  location = "southeastasia"
  primary_nic = "backendvmnic"
  #vnet_subnet_id = element(module.network.vnet_subnets, 0)
  primary_ip_conf = "backendvm"
}
```

resource module main.tf file:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "primary" {
  name     = "var.resource_group_name"
  location = "var.location"
  tags = {
        environment = "env"
    }
}
```

network module main.tf file:

```
#Create Virtual Network in Primary Resource Group
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "primary" {
  name                = "var.virtual_network"
  resource_group_name = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
  address_space       = ["var.address_space"]
  location            = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
  tags = {
        environment = "env"
    }
}

#Create Subnet in Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_subnet" "primary" {
  name                 = "var.subnet"
  resource_group_name  = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
  virtual_network_name = "module.resource.azurerm_virtual_network.primary.name"
  address_prefix       = "var.address_prefix"
#  tags = {
#        environment = "env"
#    }
}

output "subnet_id"{
  value = "module.resource.azurerm_subnet.primary.id"
  }

#Create public IP address
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "primary" {
    name                         = "var.public_ip"
    location                     = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
    resource_group_name          = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"
    allocation_method            = "Dynamic"

    tags = {
        environment = "env"
    }
}

output "public_ip_id"{
  value = "module.resource.azurerm_public_ip.id"
  }

#Create Network Interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "primary" {
  name                = "var.primary_nic"
  location            = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.location"
  resource_group_name = "module.resource.azurerm_resource_group.primary.name"

  ip_configuration {
        name                           = "var.primary_ip_conf"
        subnet_id                      = "module.resource.azurerm_subnet.primary.id"
        private_ip_address_allocation  = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id           = "module.resource.azurerm_public_ip.primary.id"
    }
  tags = {
        environment = "env"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious that, you don't have [string interpolcation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html) in strings like `var.public_ip` or `module.resource.azurerm_subnet.primary.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some places need to be corrected in your codes:

- You don't need double quotes`""` in variables or expression refers to [Interpolation Syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html). For example `"var.virtual_network"` should be `var.virtual_network`.
- You can directly reference resources in the same `main.tf` file instead of from the module block. For example, change `virtual_network_name = "module.resource.azurerm_virtual_network.primary.name"` to `virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.primary.name` in the `resource "azurerm_subnet"` block.
- The syntax for referencing module outputs is `${module.NAME.OUTPUT}`, where `NAME` is the module name given in the header of the module configuration block and `OUTPUT` is the name of the output to reference. You can declare resource group name and location in `module "network"` instead of using it from the `./modules/network/main.tf` file.

Here is the working code and you could get more references in this [document](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/azure/modules_az):

main.tf file in the root directory

```
module "resource" {
  source = "./modules/resource"
  resource_group_name = "DevOpsPoc-primary"
  location = "southeastasia"
}


module "network" {
  source = "./modules/network"
  resource_group_name = module.resource.RGname
  location = module.resource.location
  virtual_network = "primaryvnet"
  subnet = "primarysubnet"
  address_space = ["192.168.0.0/16"]
  address_prefix = "192.168.1.0/24"
  public_ip = "backendvmpip"
  primary_nic = "backendvmnic"
  #vnet_subnet_id = element(module.network.vnet_subnets, 0)
  primary_ip_conf = "backendvm"
}
```

main.tf in the directory `./modules/resource`

```
variable "resource_group_name" {}
variable "location" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "primary" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location

}

output "RGname" {
  value = "${azurerm_resource_group.primary.name}"
}

output "location" {
    value = "${azurerm_resource_group.primary.location}"
}
```

main.tf in the directory `./modules/network` and also declare the variables in the same directory.

```
#Create Virtual Network in Primary Resource Group
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "primary" {
  name                = var.virtual_network
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = var.address_space
  location            = var.location

}

#Create Subnet in Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_subnet" "primary" {
  name                 = var.subnet
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.primary.name
  address_prefix       = var.address_prefix

}

output "subnet_id"{
  value = azurerm_subnet.primary.id
  }

#Create public IP address
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "primary" {
    name                         = var.public_ip
    location                     = var.location
    resource_group_name          = var.resource_group_name
    allocation_method            = "Dynamic"

}

output "public_ip_id"{
  value = azurerm_public_ip.primary.id
  }


#Create Network Interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "primary" {
  name                = var.primary_nic
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  ip_configuration {
        name                           = var.primary_ip_conf
        subnet_id                      = azurerm_subnet.primary.id
        private_ip_address_allocation  = "Dynamic"
        public_ip_address_id           = azurerm_public_ip.primary.id
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank Nancy. It worked for me.Got confused in variables used.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when setting up an **Azure App Service** using **Terraform**.

```
module.app_service.azurerm_app_service.app_service: Creating...

│ Error: Cannot parse Azure ID: parse "27220": invalid URI for request
│ 
│   with module.app_service.azurerm_app_service.app_service,
│   on ../../../modules/azure/app-service/main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_app_service" "app_service":
│    1: resource "azurerm_app_service" "app_service" {
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I used the wrong value for the **App Service Plan ID** in my module.

I was using `27220` as the **App Service Plan ID**, instead of the actual value of the **App Service Plan ID** which of this format:

```
"/subscriptions/fec545cd-bead-43ba-84c6-5738cdc7e458/resourceGroups/MyDevRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/MyDevLinuxASP"
```

**That's all**